# Snapchat Story Upload

Tags: uploads, snapchat

How do I upload images from my photo gallery to my Snapchat story? I have heard of the Xposed module Snapshare but I don't fancy rooting my phone permanently.

What I want to do is, say if I downloaded an image from [APOD](http://apod.nasa.gov/apod/astropix.html), I would like to add that to my story.

Answer (score 1):

Snapchat for android has been updated with the ability to upload screenshots to chats, my story etc.

Comment: How do you upload to the story?

Answer (score 0):

Once you finish editing your Snap, you are taken to a screen where you can choose the recipients of your Snap. My Story is on the top of the list.

Comment: How do you upload the photo in the first place then?

Comment: @user12321 Refer to [this picture.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5hcMINYAv2WRGpyc1RaNVdsaEE/edit?usp=docslist_api) Evidence of My Story can be seen [here.](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B5hcMINYAv2WTjl1RF9henhKa0E/edit?usp=docslist_api) But seriously, is it really hard to use Snapchat for Android? The interface is pretty much the same.

Comment: Oh, I see, I was meaning uploading images from your gallery. Say I downloaded one of those screenshots, I would like to add it to my story.

Comment: I'm so sorry ;_; You can do this with root using an Xposed module called [Snapshare.](http://repo.xposed.info/module/net.cantab.stammler.snapshare)

Comment: Ah no, it's fine! Yeah, I've heard of Snapshare just the idea of rooting my phone isn't very enticing.